# Nice way to get Windows API call arguments in WinDBG

Tags: windbg

How do I get a nice list of call arguments for well documented functions such as kernel32!CreateRemoteThread in windbg? Right now when a breakpoint hits I manually decode them considering the architecture and stdcall vs fastcall convention. I feel there must be a better way.